# step function question: What tools can be used to study it?

Tags: analysis, prime-numbers, zeta-functions, step-function, desmos

Consider the step function

$$A(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{\mathrm{floor}\bigg(\frac{\log n}{\log x}\bigg)+\mathrm{floor}\bigg(\frac{\log n}{\log (1-x)}\bigg)} = \prod_{\mathrm{ p~ prime}} \frac{1}{1-e^{\mathrm{floor}\bigg(\frac{\log p}{\log x}\bigg)+\mathrm{floor}\bigg(\frac{\log p}{\log (1-x)}\bigg)}} $$

[image]

Here is $A(x)$ generalized to one higher dimension. (desmos struggles to render it)

[image]

$A(x)$ cannot be studied using analytic techniques clearly, but it does behave in a way like a zeta function because of its description as a product of primes.

> What does one make of this "non-analytic" structure that's expressible as primes? Could $A(x)$ be useful in some respect and what tools could be used to study it, if analytic tools are out the window?

Comment: You could perhaps use the Fourier series for the floor function $$\lfloor x\rfloor =x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi} \underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^K \frac{\sin(2 k \pi x)}{k}\right)$$ to at least make it continuous in the interval $0<x<1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why complicate things with the floor function?

I suggest you study

$$f(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{\frac{\log(n)}{\log(s)}+\frac{\log(n)}{\log(1-s)}}=\zeta \left(-\frac{1}{\log (s)}-\frac{1}{\log (1-s)}\right),\quad0<\Re(s)<1\tag{1}$$

with functional equation

$$f(s)=f(1-s)$$

which is illustrated in the Figure below.

[image: Illustration of formula (1) for f(s)]

Comment: I don't believe $f(s)$ is related to $A(x)$ so why study $f(s)$?

Comment: Because $\frac{f(x)+(c-1)}{c}$ seems to approximate $A(x)$ for $0<x<1$ to some degree (or vice versa), $f(s)$ is directly related to $\zeta(s)$, $A(x)$ is only valid for $0<x<1$ since the floor function is only defined for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and I suspect $A(x)$ is a dead end because as you pointed out its non-analytic. How many terms did you evaluate in the first plot in your question above? What is the higher dimension (third axis) in the second plot in your question above?

Comment: I evaluated that first plot to 200 terms. I'll update the post to reflect the equation for the higher dimensional plot